# SSIS: OnPostExecute OnError issue

Tags: ssis, onerror

I have a SSIS package where I set the OnError and OnPostExecute event handlers.
The Package is a simple loop container and the handler OnPostExecute is working fine.

But the OnError is not actually working. Ive added some wrong-code to the task inside the Loop, just for the sake of testing the OnError handler and it's not activating. The OnPostExecute handler does work after very process inside the Loop.

On the other hand, Ive tried executing the OnError task by its own and it did work. So, it's not being activated when an error happens.

Some information. I have set the Propagate system variable to FALSE for every task inside the loop since I dont want the package to stop. (maybe this has something to do with it)
The OnError handler is at **package** level.

Any idea about OnError not being executed when the process finds an error?
Thanks

Comment: question1: does it work when propagate is TRUE? question 2: how are you running the package? f5?

Comment: 1. No, it doesnt work, the difference is the procedure stops after first error. But OnError is not being activated. 2. Im running it with the play button using the mouse, and Ive also tried with F5. thanks

Comment: Did you solved your problem? With the default Log Provider for SQL Server I can't get any OnError event on my dbo.sysssislog table, even if I see the error while debugging in the Execution Results tab. My goal was to avoid custom OnError event handlers.

Comment: I haven't to be honest. Thanksfully I was able to move on since the errors inside the loop are not critical. Im pretty sure it has something to do with the package itself because other ones did activated the OnError event when something went wrong. And yes, I'm always using a custom event handler cause of company reasons.

Comment: After some digging I solved my problem. I was using the RetainSameConnection=true property on my connection manager (I'm managing transactions inside the package) and I was sharing it between Logging and the package tasks. When I've disabled RetainSameConnection, I've obtained the expected OnError events. The solution was to create another connection manager exclusively for Logging.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "DisableEventHandlers" property. Make sure it is set to false on any of the tasks that it is not firing.